# Simulate memory warning on modal view controller cleans the previous controller's content

Tags: objective-c, ipad, modalviewcontroller, didreceivememorywarning

I have a modal view controller as main controller in my app. In the one flow it can present another modal view controller over it. 
So the problem is when I'm trying to simulate memory warning on this second view controller, main view controller receives `- [didReceiveMemoryWarning:]` message, but it's `- [viewDidUnload:]` doesn't get called.  Despite it, when second view controller is dissmissed, all content from the main one disappears.
Can somebody give me a clue what should I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A modal's relationship with it's parent doesn't allow it (the parent) to release while it's presenting a child. Which is why viewDidUnload doesn't get called. It would be bad news if your parent left while a child was up, there wouldn't be anything to dismiss back to creating null references and disaster.

If you releasing anything in the `-[didRecieveMemoryWarning]` method of your main controller then this is why it's disappearing when you go back to it.

Hope this helps.